# Programatically create, train and publish a LUIS model

Tags: c#, nlp, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

Can we programatically create, train and publish a LUIS model from C#. Do we have any SDK available? If we want to add a new intent or entity or create a Utterance and book mark this we need to do this via luis.ai can we get this done via C# code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in C# by using the [Luis Programmatic API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f). You can also use the [SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows).

Comment: If I have understood you correct .. using this we can invoke LUIS in our code and start using this .. I want to create a LUIS model programatically instead of doing it using luis.ai website. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can create apps, etc with that API, for example: https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de47b

Comment: I added the reference to the SDK https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows

Comment: im trying to use the Luis Programmatic API,
Add new exemple   ok
train model              ok
publish                     nOk
i have a 400 bad request 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Cannot find an application with the specified ID"
  }
}
im using the application id from Botframework , any idea about this problem ?

Comment: You need to use the application ID from LUIS not from the Bot Framework

Answer (score 0):

You use LUIS (Microsoft Cognitive Services for NLP) in your bots or applications and have always wanted to create intentions, entities, train your template and publish it programmatically, now you can!
I developed an SDK for .NET that allows you to do this and more!
It is an open-source project and is available on my GitHub with installation and usage details. It even has a roadmap with the features of the next version!
If you liked it, so follow me and give a star there on the project! Thanks!

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cognitive.LUIS.Programmatic

GitHub: https://github.com/andreluizsecco/Cognitive-LUIS-Programmatic